# blender running slow when deforming mesh with normal map

Tags: materials, normals, normal-map, performance

I have a pretty powerful pc that should run this perfectly but I'm getting a lot of lag when doing this. when I deform anything that has a normal map, it doesn't want to handle it very well and it even does this with no other textures besides the normal map. earlier I did mess around with the actual normals of the model but that doesn't seem to do anything when I replicate the issue on other models. in fact, they all get the same issue of not being able to handle a normal. I know this site really doesn't like performance questions but the reddit wasn't too much help

even this causes it to be slow

[image]

[here is the blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1swAjmGG0lps7cs_0DHIDT7RaWQuNY0wQ/view?usp=sharing)

let me know if textures are needed. although they really shouldn't be

Comment: Performance when deforming a mesh that requires normal information is slow for reasons mentioned in this report: https://developer.blender.org/T64458, but i can neither say if this is limited to eevee nor judge if a performance of ~5fps when moving or re-posing is lower than usual.

Comment: working great so far. thanks!